# How to improve the gRPC development?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

I find it's tedious to define the `protobuf message` again in the `.proto` file after the entity model is ready.

For example, exposure the `CRUD` operations through gRPC you need to define the `table schema` in `.proto` files in a `message` way because gRPC requires it.

In traditional `restful` API development, we don't need to define the `messages` because we just return some `json`, and the `json` object can be arbitrary.

Any suggestions?

P.S. I know the gRPC is more efficient than `restful` APIs at run time. However I find it's far less efficient than `restful` APIs at development time.

Before I found the elegant way to improve the efficiency I currently use an ugly way: define a `JSON message type`:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package user;
service User {
    rpc FindOneByJSON(JSON) returns (JSON) {}
    rpc CreateByJSON(JSON) returns (JSON) {}
}
message JSON {
    string value = 1;
}
```

It's ugly because it need the invoker to `JSON.stringify()` the arguments and `JSON.parse()` the response.

Comment: I'm not much experienced here, but even JSON based APIs need a structure to marshal and unmarshal from. I don't see how writing those is any different? GRPC is saving you time writing all those parsers and even the http level code to establish connections with no need for HTTP methods either. With JSON APIs people usually end up spending time with Swagger codegen just to avoid writing API parsers. "Faster" is relative here. And defining a proto for GRPC saves a hell of a lot of time in writing code for multiple clients, across a lot of languages.

Comment: Thank you @ishaan, another relative question: How to manage those proto files across different projects? If I updated the proto files in the server project, I need to also update those files in the relevant client projects. Copy Paste? git subtree? Any better ways?

Comment: Well, if you're using something like Node.JS, GoLang, Dart or even Java, you can always fetch new dependencies on build (`package.json`, `pubspec.yaml`, `deps` & `gradle`). This is easiest with GoLang & Node.JS, if nothing works, submodules. But sometimes when you're generating proto clients, it adds protoc version dependencies to them, so if your build tools for the client don't match them, the proto clients don't work, happens quite frequently with dart. So, either you always pull the definitions and generate client yourself or you pull clients and solve the upgrade issues if any.

Answer (score 2):

Because gRPC and REST follow different concepts.

In REST, the server maintains the state and you just control it from the client (that's what you use GET, POST, PUT, UPDATE, DELETE request types for). In contrast, a procedure call has a well-defined return type that is reliable and self-describing. gRPC does not follow the concept of the server being the single source of truth concerning an object's state; instead -- conceptually -- you can interact with the server using regular calls, as you would on a local setup.

By the way, in good RESTful design, you do use schemas for your JSON returns, so in fact it is *not* arbitrary, even though you can abuse it to be. For example, check the [OpenAPI 3 specification for the response object definition](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.0.md#responses-object-example): They usually contain references to schemas.